# Do circadian hormones fluctuations follow sleeping patterns or the time of day?

Tags: endocrinology, sleep, circadian-rhythms

It is said that testosterone and cortisol are at their highest early in the morning, at 8 am, and lowest at night.

What happens, though, if someone regularly goes to sleep at 8 am and wakes up in the afternoon/evening over a long period? What happens if sleep times are inconsistent, sometimes sleeping overnight and sometimes in the morning? Do hormonal fluctuations follow the sleep pattern or do they follow the time of day?

Comment: I think your question will be better received without the "I" parts of it, so I've edited it accordingly. Additionally, it's good to provide citations for things you read about, so if you can cite where you read about daily cycles of testosterone and cortisol that would be great.